# Why are USB drives incapable of booting an entire OS long-term?

Tags: boot, usb-flash-drive

Through reading several articles and forum submissions, I have come to the (perhaps incorrect) conclusion that one cannot download in entirely the Ubuntu OS onto a flash drive. The answers that I found were those saying that if I could manage to download all of the OS onto a USB flash drive, that I would be unable to keep that USB healthy for very long, perhaps only lasting a few months.

Why are USB flash drives so incompetent compared to, say, an external hard drive in storing and booting data for long periods of time?

Comment: @OpticalResonator:  I can recall either being told or reading years ago, something along the lines of how USB memory devices had a high resistance component in them to retain their memory states. To store anything on them a high voltage signal had to sent to overcome the high resistance element. Every time this happened it weakened the resistance element which caused such memory devices to have a limited amount of write cycles to them. This may explain why they can't be used as a long term OS boot device.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [If USB sticks and/or external drives have limits, I mean on the number of writes and deletes, how about reads and copys?](https://superuser.com/questions/629630/if-usb-sticks-and-or-external-drives-have-limits-i-mean-on-the-number-of-writes)

Comment: I run Ubuntu and other distros on a flash drive all the time.  The main issue is that regular flash drives have unreliable service lives, they're basically disposable.  You use them until they die.  So if you want to use one to operate from, buy a "good quality" (i.e., with a decent warranty), fast drive and have a backup.  I wouldn't trust one for anything "mission critical".  But my expectation is a few years of service.

Comment: You absolutely can run a full Linux OS on a USB stick.  I have been running OpenMediaVault off a 2GB USB drive for over a year now.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

USB Flash drives undergo frequent use and abuse, whereas SSDs and HDDs are not subject to the abuse which flash drives suffer. Even if the USB was plugged in, once, and left in place, the circuitry design is not as robust as an SSD.

In addition, a LiveUSB (i.e., bootable) must be prepared in a special way to retain data and new apps, and that 'persistence' is limited to 4MB, which is hardly suitable for practical use.

Incidentally, they are also significantly slower than an SSD, for the USB interface is nowhere near the 6GT/sec of a SATA 3 drive, as [you can see in this review](https://usb.userbenchmark.com/).

Comment: I'd like to see a source for the inferior circuitry claim. The primary issue with installs on plain old flash is that it wears down very quickly. That's the reason why persistence files are a thing: the OS operates in RAM and only writes to flash as little as possible to minimize wear. Putting a regular install on a USB flash drive is perfectly doable without any extra hoops - it's just that it will kill the drive very quickly.

Answer (score 2):

Yes and no. If you plan to use a standard OS meant for common desktop, you're going to kill the flash, wearing off its write cycles soon - the OS performs a plenty of writing: logs, temporary files etc. and they all take toll on the flash.

There are solutions for embedded systems though, that involve using UnionFS - a special meta-filesystem that overlays two different filesystems as if they were one. In this case, the flash is overlaid with a ramdisk. The flash is mounted read-only, and all common writes are performed to a virtual disk in RAM (copying relevant file from flash first, if needed), which lasts as long as the power is on; any corruption or errors can be cleaned up by cycling the power. If persistent changes need to be introduced (usually by authorized service), the flash is remounted read-write, and the changes are made to the files on the mount path of that flash medium, not the root directory tree, which is still UnionFS.

Comment: Anything you can link to (or can you elaborate) on setting up UnionFS with a ramdisk?  Would that work only with embedded systems, or could you implement that on a flash drive with a "portable" OS?

Comment: @fixer1234: It would work with a "portable" OS, but it's cumbersome for saving anything. An example of such configuration: http://blog.pi3g.com/2014/04/make-raspbian-system-read-only/

Comment: Update: currently the cumbersome work is replaced with one choice made in raspi-config